# unknown chars %3cb added while creating html file

Tags: html, copy-paste

I'm trying to update a html file. which has following tags

> The **tune2fs** allows you to convert an **ext2** file system to

The content is available on online-html editor,when copy-paste(ctrl/c + ctrl+v)  the content and add it file, it becomes

> he+%3Cb%3Etune2fs%3C%2Fb%3E+allows+you+to+convert+an+%3Cb%3Eext2%3C%2Fb%3E+file+system

does copy/paste adds some chars? Why this happens and is it possible to prevent this?

this is not programming question, but something like copy/paste buffer or creates this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is HTML that has been URL encoded into `<b>` and `</b>` tags. You can change `"%3Cb%3E"` to `"<b>"` and `"%3C%2Fb%3E"` to `"</b>"`. Also note that `+` is the URL encoded form of `" "` (space). Alternatively, you could plug it into any [URLDecoder](http://www.albionresearch.com/misc/urlencode.php) and it will decode it for you.

Comment: that's fast response :) thanks for the answer. Will use URLDecoder.